# How to initialize object's manager w/o initializing object in shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I want to use smart pointers in this way:

```
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<string> foo;
weak_ptr<string> bar (foo);
foo = make_shared<string>("some string");
cout << *bar.lock(); // SIGSEGV
```

The clue is how to initialize `shared_ptr`'s object manager without construction the object (`string` in this case). Is it even possible? I could use default ctor of the object and later use copy/move assignment. But may some more elegant solution exist?

It is worth for me that the object won't be initialized - it would be a lie in logic if I would initialize the shared_ptr with empty value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The core of this idea is to use nested pointers: `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<MYTYPE>>`. In my case I created a wrapping template:

```
template<typename T>
class LazyInitializator : public std::unique_ptr<T> {
public:
    LazyInitializator() : std::unique_ptr<T>() {} // this ctor offers lazy initialization
    LazyInitializator(const T& val) : std::unique_ptr<T> (std::make_unique<T>(val)) {} // for normal construction
    LazyInitializator& operator= (const T& val) { 
        if (!std::unique_ptr<T>::operator bool()) // if object wasn't constructed
            std::unique_ptr<T>::operator= (std::make_unique<T>(val)); // construct it
        **this = val; // use assingment op provided by T - no unneccessary mem allocation
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Thanks to it I can use `shared_ptr`s in easier way. I can do sth like this:

```
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<LazyInitializator<string>> foo = make_shared<LazyInitializator<string>>();
weak_ptr<LazyInitializator<string>> bar (foo);
*foo = "some string";
cout << **bar.lock();
```

Yes, I know, looks a bit tricky, but it is the best solution for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this instead:

```
shared_ptr<string> foo = make_shared<string>();
weak_ptr<string> bar (foo);
*foo = "some string":
```

That way you are actually sharing a *string*. What you described is more like sharing a shared pointer.

Comment: I know about this possibility :) But it is worth for me that the object won't be initialized - I use it in a large program and it will be perfect for me if I manage to create only object manager, but not the object.

Comment: @user3545806 hmm, so should I search solution with some nested pointers? I mean: `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<string>>`

Comment: I am sorry was answering other question.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok, thanks. I'm thinking about some additional class for lazy initialization too. I'll check in code which solution will be the best and I post it.